# Finding items inside a list

Tags: python, list, pycharm

Trying to make a program that always finds the two even from a list in a list (at least from the top level list) . And this is what I have so far.

```
List_Test = [[2]]

if 2 in List_Test:
    print("Found!")
elif 2 in List_Test[0][0]:
    print("Found in an inner list!")
elif 2 not in List_Test:
    print("Not Found.")
```

I keep coming up with a

```
TypeError of : argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The issue is at here `elif  2 in List_Test[0][0]` which is evaluated to `2 in 2`.

Comment: Change this `elif 2 in List_Test[0][0]:` to this `elif 2 in List_Test[0]:`.

Comment: That worked thanks! But I'm still a little confused on how to apply this code to make sure that I can find the 2 in any number of brackets within the list. like if it wasn't just [[2]] but [[[2]]] and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

You can try iterating over all elements inside List_Test

```
List_Test = [[2], 2, [1,3]]

def check(row):
    if type(row) == int:
        return "Found!" if row == 2 else "Not Found."
    elif type(row) == list and 2 in row:
        return "Found in an inner list!"
    else:
        return "Not Found."

print([check(row) for row in List_Test])
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you can have more than one elements in the list, try the below code.

```
def check_for_element(list_, element):
    for i in list_:
        if i == element:
            print("Found!")
            return
        elif type(i) is list and 2 in i:
                print("Found in an inner list!")
                return
    print("Not Found")

check_for_element([3, 7, [9], [3, 2, 4]], 2)
```

Output:

> Found in an inner list!

***Note***: `elif 2 not in List_Test` is redundant and not required.